# javaMail with Lotus server

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, lotus-domino

im facing some problems with Lotus server. 
The guy that is in charge of the server is telling me that the configuration is ok, but i cant send mail with html body with his lotus server.

The error i get is : “554 Relay rejected for policy reasons.”

When i tried on my pc, i used smpt.gmail.com and worked like a champ. So i believe is not a code problem and the issue is with the server configuration.

Is there a problem with javaMail and Lotus? is it a common issue? (in one blog some guy was saying that it can not be possible to send html but i cant believe that)

My code just in case,

```
public void sendEmail(String toEmailAddr, String subject, String issue) {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", port);

    Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
    Message simpleMessage = new MimeMessage(mailSession);

    InternetAddress toAddress = null;
    InternetAddress toAddress2[] = null;
    Transport t = null ;    

    try {
        Multipart mp = new MimeMultipart();
        MimeBodyPart htmlPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        htmlPart.setContent(issue, "text/html");
        mp.addBodyPart(htmlPart);
        simpleMessage.setContent(mp);
    } catch (MessagingException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }       
    try {
        toAddress = new InternetAddress(toEmailAddr);
        toAddress2 = new InternetAddress [1];
        toAddress2[0] = toAddress;          
    } catch (AddressException e) {
        // TODO LOG 
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        simpleMessage.setRecipients(RecipientType.TO, toAddress2);
        simpleMessage.setSubject(subject);          
        t = mailSession.getTransport("smtp");       
        if(userPwd==null)
            userPwd = "";
        t.connect(host, userName, userPwd);
        t.sendMessage(simpleMessage, simpleMessage.getAllRecipients());
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        // TODO LOG 
    }finally{
        try {
            t.close();
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            // TODO LOG 
        }
    }
}
```

Regards.

Comment: Have you tried using the Domino SMTP server with a regular mail client, for example thunderbird? `Message rejected for policy reasons` can mean more or less anything, and it can be either a misconfiguration or a deliberate setting.

Comment: well at first it must be with lotus server. its my first time doing this so if u can give me some web to read about dominio SMTP would be nice.

Comment: Can you read the Domino server console and/or the server while trying to send? That might give more detailed error messages.

Answer (score 3):

SMTP on the Domino server has most likely been set up to only allow relay by certain hosts - therefore the error message `554 Relay rejected for policy reasons`.

You should talk to the admin and have him change the configuration to allow relay by other hosts. This is configured in a configuration document in the Router/SMTP -> Restrictions and Controls -> SMTP Inbound Controls section. More information on SMTP inbound relay controls is available here:
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.help.domino.admin.doc%2FDOC%2FH_SETTING_INBOUND_RELAY_CONTROLS_STEPS.html

Comment: relay is allow. Atm we can send mails throw telnet but still having the same problem.

Comment: 554 is, as Per Henrik already explained, definately a server errror message. Try sending via Telnet from the machine your code runs on and use the sender and recipient your code would use.

Comment: Agreed.  This is definitely a server configuration issue.  It is denying the relay.  When you connect through telnet, are you sending to the same toEmailAddr? Are you connecting from the same computer where your Java code runs?  And another question: are you using AUTH LOGIN in your telnet session? Also, is host an IP address or is it a DNS name?  If it is a DNS name, and your server has multiple IP addresses, are you sure it is resolving to the internal network IP address instead of an external address?

Comment: Also, you should ask your server administrator to turn on SMTPDebug=3 and SMTPDebugIO=4 on the server for a test, so that you can watch the SMTP conversation and see exactly what your Java code is sending.  Then compare it to what you see in the telnet test.  Here is a link to information about these settings: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27003007  Note: you should only turn these settings on briefly during the test, and then disable them.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem and solved it. The FROM part was "me@example.com" and changed it to "myname@mydomain.com" and it began to send

Answer (score 0):

May require Secure Connection(SSL), Use the following properties to connect mail server supporting smtp protocol:

```
    properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "SMTP_PORT");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "SMTP_SERVER_HOST_NAME_OR_IP");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
```